# cakephp 3 controllers cakedc plugin

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to use the user plugin cakeDC with cakephp 3. I followed the documention and I can log a user, list users and that's all. For other actions I have an error :

```
Error: CakeDC/Users.EditController could not be found.

Error: Create the class EditController below in file: C:\wamp\www\cake/vendor/cakedc/users/src\Controller\EditController.php
```

My functions edit, delete... are defined in `src/Controller/Users/UsersController.php` but it doesn't recognize them except index().

What should I try?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where can I change it? And is it normal to have templates, controllers and models in parallel between the plugin and app?

Comment: localhost/users and localhost/login are working. But the other functions in my UsersController.php doesn't work if I try : localhost/users/edit. I installed the plugin with the docs and build the user table. After that, I baked templates, controller and model with the console in my `src/`

Comment: You've loaded [that plugin's routes file](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Config/routes.php) at a guess and don't really want to.

Comment: OK thanks, I tried to modify some roots and it's okay... Not really optimized but it works.

Comment: When you're satisfied - please answer your own question (and when permitted, accept it) and edit the question so it contains enough information to be useful to other readers. Any details you've put in comments should be _in the question_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the routes.php. I tried the routes like https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Config/routes.php and modified them. It's not optimized but it works.